# Magento 2 Auto scaling not happening

Tags: magento, magento2

I am migrating site from magento 1.9 to magento 2.1.6

Everything has been done successfully, but there is one issue on which I am stuck.

I have dumped product images from magento 1.9.2(media/catalog/products) to magento 2.1.6(pub/media/catalog/products). Images are appearing in the frontend, but there is a issue in the listing page.

In listing page resized images are not used. It uses the original image used in webiste, due to which images on product listing page are not in a proper proportion, some are big and some are small images.

I want to have proportionate images on listing page, please let me know how can I fix the issue.

When I checked the theme source code and my website source code i found the issue.

MY code Image URL: www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/0d5164699863645cb07eac70d269722a/m/l/ml06-c_1.jpg

and Demo theme Image URL:
www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/**small_image/250x250**/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/0/7/07_1.jpg

I also tried php bin/magento catalog:images:resize still couldn't find the solution.

Please let me know what should be the possible solution of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally found the solution for my problem.
It is because I have used mageto version as 2.1.6 and theme version as 2.1.5
So I updated the theme to 2.1.6 and then php bin/magento catalog:images:resize this command, issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command

magento setup:static-content:deploy

It will generate all the required static content.(including cache files in pub)